# signalR web farm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

I have successfully used signalR to create a simple chat application inside ASP.NET MVC3. Everything works great locally on my dev machine.

Will the application work the same way in a web farm environment with multiple web servers (going live for example)? How does signalR manage its Hubs across those servers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please see David Fowler's blog post about webfarm support in SignalR v0.5: http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2012/05/02/signalr-0-5.aspx

In short, SignalR currently supports Redis and Windows Azure Service Bus as a way to communicate between multiple servers in a webfarm.

Comment: I am wondering about the current state of Redis support as the Redis links on the SignalR wiki http://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki have gone missing in the last few days. The SignalR.Redis project is still around with an example of setup however.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that too. David is currently working on a new message bus for the next version, so maybe the Redis transport needs an update when it is ready and was therefore removed. Redis should work in v0.5.2 however.